# Is this sentence correct? In used as

Tags: grammaticality

I wanna know that this sentence is grammatically correct or not:

In used as ’disagreement ’, ’dispute’ and ’debate’ have almost the same meaning.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have read this sentence somewhere, it could be a misprint for "**If** used as...", meaning that the two words have a similar meaning when they are used to mean 'disagreement'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This is not grammatically correct.

Deconstructing the sentence:

> ’disagreement ’, ’dispute’ and ’debate’ have almost the same meaning.

This is grammatically correct, although you could include an Oxford comma.

> used as ’disagreement ’, ’dispute’ and ’debate’ have almost the same meaning.

This is also correct. I wouldn't include an Oxford comma in this instance.

> In used as ’disagreement ’, ’dispute’ and ’debate’ have almost the same meaning.

Now, it's pretty obvious where the problem is coming from – you generally can't follow an introductory preposition like "in" with a past-tense verb like "used." Here's another [explanation/example of this type of misuse](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/prepositions/rules-for-prepositions.html):

> Prepositions must always be followed by a noun or pronoun. That noun is called the object of the preposition. A verb can't be the object of a preposition.
>
> "The bone was for the dog." This is correct- the preposition for is followed by the noun "dog."
>
> "The bone was for walked." This is not correct. The preposition for is followed by a verb "walked." Walked can't be the object of a preposition.

You can easily resolve this type of erroneous sentence by converting the inappropriate preposition into an appropriate adverb:

> When used as 'disagreement,' 'dispute' and 'debate' have almost the same meaning.

You can also sometimes resolve these sentences by using a gerund form of your verb as a noun, although I find this to be more awkward than beginning with an adverb:

> In [using/this use of] ’disagreement ’, ’dispute’ and ’debate’ have almost the same meaning.